# Generate AWS credentials for accessing S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a couple of S3 buckets and I want to access them from an app. How do I generate AWS credentials with access restricted to those buckets? I suppose it would require using IAM users and groups.

Comment: The below URL describe in details how to create credentials for an IAM user to access s3 bucket https://objectivefs.com/howto/how-to-restrict-s3-bucket-policy-to-only-one-aws-s3-bucket also, this link is very helpful https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/1455-amazon-s3-creating-an-iam-user

Comment: @Stargazer I'm working on a prewritten app and just needed credentials to shove in it.

Comment: Be aware that IAM user credentials are not the best option for application use. They are persistent credentials, so if they're leaked then the window of exposure is wider. Ideally, you would retrieve temporary (STS) credentials.

Comment: Do you mean a mobile app?